# How to render an img in html with jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, jspdf

I want to convert my web page to pdf, but having a jspdf image does not render the web for me, it leaves my screen blank and I get the following error: jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>prueba</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1 class="mx-5 my-5">prueba okey</h1>

    <div class="contianer my-5 mx-5" id="prueba1">
        <img src="img/debian.png" alt="">
        <h1>texto en grande</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi assumenda, modi nihil adipisci quia nesciunt
        repellendus ab laboriosam illo suscipit corporis illum fugiat eum soluta eius! Eaque nisi veniam ratione.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quod at cumque sapiente illum eveniet minus
        nostrum laboriosam beatae facilis omnis nemo, impedit fugit, autem molestiae ex culpa itaque labore?

        <h4>El usuario {{usuario.nombre}} {{usuario.apellidos}} trabaja como {{usuario.trabajo}}</h4>
    </div>




    <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var elementHTML = $('#prueba1').html();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

        doc.save('sample-document.pdf');

    </script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></s`introducir el código aquí`cript>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know how I can solve it, and I would also like to know if it is possible to display the dpf on the web without it being downloaded automatically, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the image as a base64-encoded image directly in the CSS

or else try to use Html2Canvas npm module and use pdf.addHTML() instead of pdf.fromHTML().

Example code snippet:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.addHTML($('#IDOfHTMLElementToConvertToPdf')[0], () => {
    pdf.save('filename.pdf');
});
```